# How to I output org.w3c.dom.Element to string format in java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an `org.w3c.dom.Element` object passed into my method. I need to see the whole xml string including its child nodes (the whole object graph).  I am looking for a method that can convert the `Element` into an xml format string that I can `System.out.println` on.  Just `println()` on the 'Element' object won't work because `toString()` won't output the xml format and won't go through its child node.  Is there an easy way without writing my own method to do that? Thanks.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219596/how-to-i-output-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-format-in-java

Answer (score 170):

Assuming you want to stick with the standard API...

You could use a [DOMImplementationLS](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/DOMImplementationLS.html):

```
Document document = node.getOwnerDocument();
DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document
    .getImplementation();
LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
String str = serializer.writeToString(node);
```

If the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> declaration bothers you, you could use a [transformer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html) instead:

```
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node),
      new StreamResult(buffer));
String str = buffer.toString();
```

Comment: This is the solution if you are getting [html: null] and would expect the HTML.
Added this comment so that google can index the answer hopefully.

Comment: You can still use LSSerializer and output "UTF-8".  Use LSOutput with StringWriter instead and set the encoding type to "UTF-*8"

Comment: Works with w3c Document object as well

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>` declaration bothers...  we can also add this line `serializer .getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", false);`  in first solution....

Comment: thanks for your answer, that's really great. But I have a problem with it, sometimes some tags of the matched parts are removed and the text content of them is displayed solely. Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Oneliner: `((org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS)element.getOwnerDocument().getImplementation()).createLSSerializer().writeToString(element)`

Comment: Both approaches fail if there are namespace prefixes defined in an "outer" element. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56872970/274677

Comment: One problem with this approach is that it's extremely inefficient.  The `createLSSerializer()` method results in the `WebappClassLoaderBase` having to reload the class every time you want to write an XML element to a string.  If your application is trying to do this thousands of times per second, it's not really feasible.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 17):

Simple 4 lines code to get `String` *without xml-declaration* (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`) from `org.w3c.dom.Element`

```
DOMImplementationLS lsImpl = (DOMImplementationLS)node.getOwnerDocument().getImplementation().getFeature("LS", "3.0");
LSSerializer serializer = lsImpl.createLSSerializer();
serializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", false); //by default its true, so set it to false to get String without xml-declaration
String str = serializer.writeToString(node);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [jcabi-xml](http://xml.jcabi.com) with one liner:

```
String xml = new XMLDocument(element).toString();
```

Comment: New versions of jcabi-xml don't support Element as param, only Node/File/String.

Answer (score 2):

Not supported in the standard JAXP API, I used the JDom library for this purpose. It has a printer function, formatter options etc. http://www.jdom.org/

Comment: +1 for it not being the intent of the standard org.w3c.dom API. If I'm interested in blocks of XML as text, I usually just try to parse it out as text with a regex match (if the search criteria is easily represented as a regex).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the schema of the XML or can otherwise create JAXB bindings for it, you could use the JAXB Marshaller to write to System.out:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRootElement
public class BoundClass {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String test;

    @XmlElement
    private int x;

    public BoundClass() {}

    public BoundClass(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jxbc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BoundClass.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jxbc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement(new QName("root"),BoundClass.class,new Main("test")),System.out);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what i s done in jcabi:

```
private String asString(Node node) {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        // @checkstyle MultipleStringLiterals (1 line)
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
        if (!(node instanceof Document)) {
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        }
        trans.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));
    } catch (final TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    } catch (final TransformerException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
    }
    return writer.toString();
}
```

and it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

With [VTD-XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365208/speeding-up-xpath), you can pass into the cursor and make a single getElementFragment call to retrieve the segment (as denoted by its offset and length)... Below is an example

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
public class concatTest{
    public static void main(String s1[]) throws Exception {
        VTDGen vg= new VTDGen();
        String s = "<users><user><firstName>some </firstName><lastName> one</lastName></user></users>";
        vg.setDoc(s.getBytes());
        vg.parse(false);
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/users/user/firstName");
        int i=ap.evalXPath();
        if (i!=1){
            long l= vn.getElementFragment();
            System.out.println(" the segment is "+ vn.toString((int)l,(int)(l>>32)));
        }
    }

}
```