# Is there any range limit for XSL:VARIABLE

Tags: variables, types, range, xslt, xalan

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="//detailoption | //systemnotes">
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space(@id)!=''">~</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This loops runs for short iterations. But when the iteration increases the entire XSL fails to transform and throw an error.

> SystemId Unknown; Line #0; Column #0; java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Is there any range limitations for variable data in XSL? Is there any solution to overcome this problem?

Xalan 2.7.0 . Is there any way to find the more details of it.
Our current coding is:

```java
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
factory.setURIResolver(createURIResolver()); 
Templates template = factory.newTemplates(xslIn); 
Transformer xformer = template.newTransformer(); 
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream hndWrite = byteStream;
Result result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(hndWrite); 
xformer.transform(xmlIn, result)
```

Comment: What library (and version) are you using? Xalan?

Comment: About limitations questions, I think is important including details such as xslt processor used, xslt version, environment, ...

Comment: Xalan 2.7.0 . Is there any way to find the more details of it. Our current coding is   TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   factory.setURIResolver(createURIResolver());
   Templates template = factory.newTemplates(xslIn);
   Transformer xformer = template.newTransformer();
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   OutputStream hndWrite = byteStream;
   Result result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(hndWrite);
   xformer.transform(xmlIn, result);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you upgrade your Xalan to 2.7.1, and then try again. There had been several performance improvements and bugfixes. See the release notes on JIRA here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10584&version=10863

See also some benchmarks I recently did. An average benchmark was 2x faster with Xalan 2.7.1, rather than with 2.7.0:

[Java XPath (Apache JAXP implementation) performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340802/java-xpath-apache-jaxp-implementation-performance)