# Optimizing DOM and XPath Java code

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, jaxp

My code is too slow, but I'm not sure how to improve it. Reading from disk into DOM for a 1k-file takes about 20 ms, that might be okay depending on the disk, but then I've got another 20 ms for working on a xpath statement, which is far too much. Here is some sample code with time comments. How can I improve the code?

This happens at construction time:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = this.dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
XPathExpression[] ex = new XPathExpression[]{about 30 different expressions}
XPathExpression mainEx =xPath.compile("/rootElement/firstLevel/secondLevel");
```

Then the code:

```
Document doc = this.dBuilder.parse("somefile.xml");
//took 20 ms until here
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) mainEx .evaluate,doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
 //took another 20 ms until here !!!
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = nodes.item(i);
    for (XPathExpression e:ex) {
         String v = (String) e.evaluate(n, XPathConstants.STRING);
        if (v != null) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
    }
    //this only takes 5 ms
```

Comment: Probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340802/java-xpath-apache-jaxp-implementation-performance

Comment: Switch to VTD-XML< your problem will go away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably suffering from this problem that I documented here:

[Java XPath (Apache JAXP implementation) performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340802/java-xpath-apache-jaxp-implementation-performance)

Essentially, you should add these JVM arguments to heavily speed up Xalan's XPath implementation:

```
-Dorg.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager=
  org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault
```

or

```
-Dcom.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTMManager=
  com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault
```

Answer (score 4):

You should pre-compile your XPath expression to a [`XPathExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html), using [`XPath.compile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29).  Then call [`XPathExpression.evaluate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html#evaluate%28java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29).

This will save you time if you're executing it more than once.  I'm assuming this is the case, or 20 ms shouldn't matter.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340802/java-xpath-apache-jaxp-implementation-performance) has further information, including a JVM parameter.

Comment: I changed everything to precompiled expressions, but it doesn't really boost performance, maybe a few ms. Is there some faster way of building the dom or a faster xPath evaluator?

Comment: @Franz, so it takes almost 20 ms just to evaluate a previously compiled expression?  Which implementation are you using (I think `getClass` will tell you)?  This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340802/java-xpath-apache-jaxp-implementation-performance) indicates Xalan 2.7.1 is the fastest(of those tested), and provides a JVM parameter for optimization.

Comment: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl, should I switch?

Comment: @Franz, I believe that's bundled Xalan.  I'm not sure which version, though.  Try the JVM parameter from the question I linked.

Comment: not perfect, but it took of about 8ms. But still evaluating such a basic xPath uses 10ms.