# Parsing a xml, exponential increase in time

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a parser which parses and collects the requires fields and constructs a object out of it.
Suppose if xml is like below

```
<xml>
<p1>
...
...
</p1>
<p2>
...
</p2>
...
...
</xml>
```

My java code parses it and code seems like below.

```
for each product //p1,p2 etc..
 print start time
 parse that node, which returns a object
 print end time
 add the object to list.
```

The sample code is below

```
products = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("/xml/product",pxml,XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < products.getLength(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println("parsing product ::"+i+":" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
                BookDataInfo _parsedPoduct = ParseProduct(products.item(i));
                System.out.println("parsing product finished ::"+i+":" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
                if (_parsedPoduct.getParsingSucceeded())
                {
                    pparsedProducts.add(_parsedPoduct);
                }
            }
```

I have printed the times before parsing the node and after that, the time is exponentially increasing  with no.of products like for 1st product takes 100ms where as some 300th product takes 2000ms.
In each case same part of code is executed for parsing.
Could any one have idea why it happens?

I can't post the code what parseproduct is doing but found out where the time is consumed most.

```
private NodeList getNodelist(Node xml, String Name)
{
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Nodelist start::" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate(Name,xml,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    System.out.println("Nodelist end::" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    return nodes;
}
```

similarly for getting node value at a stmt 
Node node = (Node)xPath.evaluate(Name,xml,XPathConstants.NODE);

here xPath is a static object of type XPath.
when multiple times the above function is called for a product, the later calls are taking much time, like in start it took 2/3 ms but later(say product 300) it took 55-60ms for each call.

May I am missing some thing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Kind of hard to have an idea if we don't have the code, nor sample XSD content...

Comment: What data structure are you using to store the products?

Comment: My idea is you are reinventing the wheel. What you should try instead is to use some standard or at least wide spread library for parsing / transforming or accessing your xml.

Comment: I am using DOM parser and XPATH to get the required nodes.

Comment: Maybe you scan the document from the beginning for each element, so if you are extracting the tenth you are fast-forwarding nine elements, and if you are processing the 100th, you are fast-forwarding 99.

Comment: Data structure is java ArrayList.

Comment: In each parse I am sending the node to be parsed as argument, so I hope fast-forwarding is not happening, I edited the post with sample code aswell.

Comment: Your timing code makes no sense. You should decide to either, referring to the *current time* or referring to the *elapsed time*. But your code refers to the elapsed time since an arbitrary point hold in the variable `time` which never gets updated.   Measure elapsed time for an operation like this: `long startTimeRef=System.nanoTime(); operation(); long elapsedTime=System.nanoTime()-startTimeRef;` Btw. if `ParseProduct` really has a performance problem you can’t analyse it without looking at it so without posting the code of that method no one can tell you if there’s something wrong with it.

Comment: A technicality perhaps: your data demonstrates that the time is increasing, but not that it is increasing exponentially. It's much more likely that it is increasing quadratically. It can be useful to know the difference, because it will help identify the cause.

Comment: Updated the question with more info, May be it will give you more details for understanding the issue.

Comment: The problem is solved.
The main issue is the one mentioned in below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782618/xpath-evaluate-performance-slows-down-absurdly-over-multiple-calls

Followed the steps mentioned in that, it drastically reduced the time consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
The main issue is the one mentioned in below link.
[XPath.evaluate performance slows down (absurdly) over multiple calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782618/xpath-evaluate-performance-slows-down-absurdly-over-multiple-calls)

Followed the steps mentioned in that, it drastically reduced the time consumed.

Answer (score 0):

check out the difference between DOM and SAX parsing, DOM lets you query the XML file but have to upload entire document to memory for that, if you just want to create objects you better use SAX parser

Comment: Not just to create objects, Will do some calculation based on fields and create a object.