# how to extract entire xml element from xml document

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

all the examples about parsing xml elements/nodes, that i've found, are about how to extract node attributes/values etc from xml document.

Im interested on how should i extract an entire element from opening tag to closing tag.
Example:
from xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Employees>
        <Employee emplid="1111" type="admin"/>
    </Employees>
```

i would get the complete element

```
<Employee emplid="1111" type="admin"/>
```

to saving it in a String variable

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886531/how-to-parse-xml-with-jsoup) which uses [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: Yes, it works perfect, but is there something to make it without external libraries? Thanks a lot

Comment: I've noticed that the method doc.select() (in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886531/how-to-parse-xml-with-jsoup)  isn't key sensitive. If the xml element attributes name has some upper case characters, the returned string has lowercase :( I'm very sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do the parsing yourself, or use Android's XML parser. [This](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) shows how to use the latter.

If you use Android's parser you probably have to parse it completely, and then construct the string `<Employee emplid="1111" type="admin"/>` by hand.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Constructing the string is axactly what i don't want make. I have to take the string from a parser that extract to me the full element. It's safe for future modifies to the xml element's attributes. EDIT: P.S. i've just made the contructing way, but doesn't like to my boss :(

Answer (score 0):

For now this is the best solution.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

...

//xml document
String  xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Employees><Employee emplid=\"1111\" type=\"admin\"/></Employees>";

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
//getting the target element
NodeList list=document.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
Node node=list.item(0);    

//writing the element in the string variable
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(buffer));
String str = buffer.toString();


System.out.println(str);

...
```

Inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219596/how-to-i-output-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-format-in-java)