# XML parsing using XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Hi!
I've spent some time to parse an XML document with XPath. It seeams to be a simple task but I got in troubles since the begining. 
My code is :

```
public class QueryXML3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            //doc = builder.parse("SampleExample.xml");
            InputStream is = QueryXML3.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("SampleXml.xml");
            doc = builder.parse(is);

            XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

            // Create XPath object
            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();


            Node parNode = getParameterNode(doc, xpath);
            System.out.println("parameter node:" + parNode);

            NodeList res = getParameterNodeList(doc, xpath );
            System.out.println("List of nodes" + res);



        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static Node getParameterNode(Document doc, XPath xpath) {
        Node res = null;
        try {
            res = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/definitions/process", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static NodeList getParameterNodeList(Document doc, XPath xpath) {
        NodeList nodeList = null;
        try {
            nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/definitions/process", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for (int i = 0; i > nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.print(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName() + " ");
            }

        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nodeList;
    }
}
```

As a result i get this:

parameter node:[process: null]
List of nodes com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@2f17aadf

I just want to output all the nodes of my xml file and theire attributes...

Answer (score 0):

You are really asking how to serialize an [Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) to a string - use either a [Transformer or DOMImplementationLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219596/how-to-i-output-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-format-in-java).

The [NodeList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) type has no `toString()` contract and the implementation does not override the default `Object.toString()`. You need to iterate over the nodes and serialize each `Element` as above.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily parse an XML file in java using a 3rd party package such as [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) or [JDom](http://www.jdom.org/).

As an example, here is some simple output of an XML files elements using JSoup:

```
<note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Java code printing all elements and the selected `<from>`-element:

```
String xml = "<note>\n"
        + "<to>Tove</to>\n"
        + "<from>Jani</from>\n"
        + "<heading>Reminder</heading>\n"
        + "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n"
        + "</note>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
for (Element e : doc.children()) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

Element fromElement = doc.select("from").first();

System.out.println("\nThis is the <from>-element content:\n" + fromElement);
```