# Convert Element(org.w3c.dom) to String in Java

Tags: java, xml, element

I'm having a small issue of converting Element object to String. Because I need a string to be passed to a particular method. I've tried by using .toString() or using a String variable assigning to it. None of the trials were correct. How can we easily convert and the string object also should show the exact XML structure as it is showing for Element.

```
Element element = (Element) xmlList.item(i);
```

The above "element" object shows in XML format. I want to convert the same in String in XML format

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I output org.w3c.dom.Element to string format in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219596/how-to-i-output-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-format-in-java)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

needed packages:

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import java.io.StringWriter;
```

code:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(<your-element-obj>);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
transformer.transform(source, result);

String strObject = result.getWriter().toString();
```

Comment: Virendrao, can you please mention the packages for these classes?

Comment: Thanks.. That has converted into string. As we have discussed before. It shows string data type itself, but it is still having Node:#text

Comment: how can I remove the header of xmlversion and encoding?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the transformer API.

```
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(element), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

Comment: I don't have external API.

Comment: The String for IntelliJ's evaluation window is `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(element), new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(System.out))`